# Create calendar events in NextCloud using PHP

Tags: php, curl, put, caldav, nextcloud

I'm trying to create a calendar event in Nextcloud with PHP and cURL. After running the code from command line, I get the following error from Nextcloud 12:

```
PUT is not allowed on non-files.
```

Here is the full code I'm using following [this guide](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/#creating-a-calendar-object)

```
<?php
$url = 'https://cloud.org/remote.php/dav/calendars/mycalendars/activity/';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/calendar', 'charset=utf-8');
$userpwd = 'gerald:123';
$description = 'new event description';
$summary = 'new event';
$tstart = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime("-2 days"));
$tend = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime("-2 days"));
$tstamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z");
$uid = 'event-123';

$body = <<<__EOD
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:$tstamp
DTSTART:$tstart
DTEND:$tend
UID:$uid
DESCRIPTION:$description
LOCATION:Office
SUMMARY:$summary
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
__EOD;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

//Execute the request.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
?>
```

Does this mean that CalDAV in Nextcloud doesn't support PUT? So how do calendar applications like Thunderbird Lightning create events in Nextcloud?

In the Nextcloud [WebDAV documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/index.html) I can't find anything about CalDAV implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a HTTP `PUT` request, the intention is that you *replace* the resource at the uri that you are referencing. So your sample HTTP request is telling me that you are *replacing*:

```
https://cloud.org/remote.php/dav/calendars/mycalendars/activity
```

Is that correct? Probably not! You probably want to create a new calendar resource in that collection. So pick a new url for your resource that doesn't exist yet:

```
https://cloud.org/remote.php/dav/calendars/mycalendars/activity/foo-bar-baz.ics
```